# Is Fisher transformation appropriate for magnitude squared coherence and phase locking value?

Tags: time-series, correlation, spectral-analysis, fisher-transform

[Fisher transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation), or hyperbolic arctangent, is recommend before performing arithmetic on correlation coefficients (e.g., estimating confidence intervals), because it makes their distribution normal. I have a strong intuition that the same is true for coherence coefficients, given the similarity of Pearson correlation and coherence equations. Is it also appropriate for phase locking value, PLV ([Lachaux et al., 1999](https://doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1097-0193(1999)8:4%3C194::AID-HBM4%3E3.0.CO;2-C)), which also varies between 0 and 1? As PLV is equivalent to cross-correlation of a pair of complex analysis signals ([Aydore et al., 2013](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.neuroimage.2013.02.008)) and coherence is the normalized covariance of complex analysis signals, my hunch is that it should be.

Comment: "because it makes their distribution normal" -- well no. Firstly it doesn't make them normal, it makes them *closer* to normal. Secondly I'd tend to argue that its primary purpose (the main 'because') is to stabilize the variance, but you conveniently get an improvement in the approach to approximate normality as well (that is, you get pretty close to normality of the distribution of the transformed sample correlation at smaller sample size than it comes in for the untransformed correlation; being a kind of average the correlation will typically approach normality even when not transformed).

Comment: Very pedantic comment: Reference to arcs is best avoided here. See e,g, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions for why.  Common use of arctanh as notation for the function is not therefore good practice, but  artanh or atanh doesn't raise any of the objections documented. .